# Cambiar tipo de variable en c# o cast

Tags: c#, cast, polimorfismo

estoy intentando de implementar un proyecto en C# donde tengo un único proyecto para varios clientes diferentes.

Resumo mi modelo así no se hace muy largo.
Tengo Proveedor(id, Configuracion, blah blah)
Configuracion(datos en común de todas las configuraciones)
ConfiguracionArgentina(id,llaveprivada) Hereda de Configuracion.
ConfiguracionBolivia(id, archivo,Certificado) Hereda de Configuracion.

Lo que quiero hacer es cuando cargo el proveedor este cambie el tipo de Configuracion a la del hijo, 
Es decir si hago proveedor. si el proveedor tiene una configuracion de Argentina salga un obj de ConfiguracionArgentina.

Agrego una imagen quizá es mas descriptivo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es que el obj Proveedor se cargue en base al tipo de proveedor que reciba por base de datos, si es un proveedor de Arg el proveedor tenga en sus propiedades la configuracion de dicho proveedor (cambia para cada pais).
Al ponerle un el proveedor la propiedad Configuracion(obj) este es padre y los otros son hijos entonces no puedo ver las propiedades del hijo, pero tampoco puedo poner la propiedad ConfiguracionArgentina dentro del proveedor, no se si va a ser un obj del tipo Argentina o X pais.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agradezco.
Saludos,

Comment: interfaces?? la verdad tu pregunta mucho no se entiende

Comment: Si escribe la pregunta correctamente, seguro va a tener la respuesta de inmediato.

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por su ayuda, agregue mas información saludos!

Comment: me enrede leyendo. Seguramente usarias Herencia o interfaces con sus accesos private, public y protected segun necesites.

Comment: Por otro lado si queres traer la informacion sobre la configuracion, no entiendo donde entra el cast de tipo de proveedor, si deberian manejar las mismas propiedades el modelo y segun el proveedor mostrar o no algunas cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es usar una base de datos con herencia recomendaria evalues usar un `ORM` como ser `Entity Framework` ya que aplicar herencia a mano por `sql` no es muy simple, un orm te permitira mapear y obtener los datos de forma facil

Existen en un ORM diferentes tipos de mapeos de herencia

[Inheritance Strategy in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Como veras tienes

- Table per Hierarchy (TPH)
- Table per Type (TPT)
- Table per Concrete Class (TPC)

Quizas si son pocos valores los que cambian entre paises la mas simple sea `TPH` en donde se persiste todos en una unica tabla usando una columna como `discriminador`

[Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 1 – Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Sino la otra es crear una tabla por cada tipo

[Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

Lo bueni de `entity framework` es que podrias aplicar consultas `linq` para recuperar por algun tipo en concreto con el `OfType<>`

Igualmente si vas a recuperar un proveedor siempre recuperaras la entidad base de la cual heredan, vas a necesitas preguntar con el `is` o `castear` para acceder a las propiedades de la clase que hereda

Realice un ejemplo que podria ayudar a que no tengas tantos `ifs`

```
public class Proveedor
{
    public ConfigBase Config {get;set;}

    public T getConfig<T>() where T : ConfigBase
    {
        return this.Config as T;
    }
}

public class ConfigBase
{
}

public class ConfigArgentina : ConfigBase
{
    public string prop1{get;set;}
}

public class ConfigBolivia : ConfigBase
{
    public string prop2{get;set;}
}
```

Entonces lo usas

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Proveedor p = new Proveedor();
        var c = new ConfigBolivia();
        c.prop2 = "val2";
        p.Config = c;

        var c1 = p.getConfig<ConfigArgentina>();
        if(c1 == null){
            Console.WriteLine("No es Argentina");
        }

        var c2 = p.getConfig<ConfigBolivia>();
        if(c2 == null){
            Console.WriteLine("No es Bolivia");
        } else {
             Console.WriteLine("prop2: {0}", c2.prop2);
        }

    }
}
```

Aplicando `generics` y el cast son el `as` puedes conocer que tipo de objeto tienes asignado

Comment: Esto me ayuda mucho, es por donde debería ir, de todas maneras voy a tener que hacer X cantidad de if dependiendo los paises que tenga?

Comment: pero usando un cast quizas no lo necesites, podrias usar el `as` para que intente castear y sino es ese el que necesitas solo debes validar si obtienes un null

Comment: no me quedó muy claro, no quiero en el main estar haciendo muchos if si no que cuando traiga el proveedor este ya tenga su tipo de configuración. me explico?

Comment: Si leiste algo sobre herencia y entity framework eso se puede pero hasta cierto punto. La propiedad que defines es la clase base de la cual heredan las demas, vas a poder acceder a las propiedades hijas solo si casteas a esta. Acceder a las propiedades de las clases hijas (sin aplicar un cast) directamente no se puede.

Comment: Opciones, o pones muchos if o aplicas el `as` para recuperar la clase que necesitas y validar si es o no de ese tipo para proseguir

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda. Voy a intentarlo y te comento, Un saludo!